# Angular 2/4 How to pass/capture radio button values using Angular typescript

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new  to Angular 2/4 and typescript.. I want to get the radio button values selected for the Phone, email and address and pass  the selected values  to typescript page. client.info.ts

How do I go about getting the values of the radio button clicked in typescript from html page. I have included my typescript and html code below.
Currently this is not working

can someone help

here is my code for the

client-info.component.html(data pulled from JSOn file)

```
   <div class="section-container">
      <!--<div class="section-subtitle"> Client Information </div> -->
    <div class="message-info">
       <span>Choose a Primary Phone Number</span>
    </div>         
      <div class="section-content">
                 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  class="row">                           


                             <div  *ngFor="let a of clientsArray; let i = index;" >

                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label"><input type="radio"  name="phone"  checked value="{{a.homePhone}}"/> Home:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="phone"  [(ngModel)]="a.homePhone" checked [value]="{{a.homePhone}}"/> {{a.homePhone}} (Home)</div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label"><input type="radio"  name="phone" value="{{a.workPhone}}"/> Work:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="phone" [(ngModel)]="a.workPhone" [value]="{{a.workPhone}}"/> {{a.workPhone}} (Work)</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label"><input type="radio"  name="phone" value="{{a.mobilePhone}}"/> Mobile:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="phone" [(ngModel)]="a.mobilePhone" [value]="{{a.mobilePhone}}"/> {{a.mobilePhone}} (Mobile)</div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div fxHide.gt-sm class="divider"></div>-->
                            </div>  


                  </div>     
      </div>
   </div>      

   <!---->


     <!--Email -->

   <div class="section-container">
      <!--<div class="section-subtitle"> Client Information </div> -->
    <div class="message-info">
       <span>Email Address:</span>
    </div>         
      <div class="section-content">
                 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  class="row">                           

                             <div  *ngFor="let a of clientsArray; let i = index;" >

                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 1:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="email"   [(ngModel)]="a.email1" checked [value]="{{a.email1}}"/>{{a.email1}}</div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 2:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="email"  [(ngModel)]="a.email12" [value]="{{a.email2}}"/>{{a.email2}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 3:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="email"  [(ngModel)]="a.email13" [value]="{{a.email3}}"/>{{a.email3}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div fxHide.gt-sm class="divider"></div>-->
                            </div>  


                  </div>     
      </div>
   </div>      

   <!---->



     <!--Address-->

   <div class="section-container">
      <!--<div class="section-subtitle"> Client Information </div> -->
    <div class="message-info">
       <span>Address:</span>
    </div>         
      <div class="section-content">
                 <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row"  class="row">                           

                             <div  *ngFor="let a of clientsArray; let i = index;" >

                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 1:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="address"  [(ngModel)]="a.address1" [value]="{{a.address1}}"/>{{a.address1}}</div>
                                </div>
                                 <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 2:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="a.address2" [value]="{{a.address3}}"/>{{a.address2}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="group" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                <!--<div fxFlex="100" class="label">Address 3:</div>-->
                                <!--<div fxFlex="60" class="data">{{loanModel.getSsn()}}</div>-->
                                 <div fxFlex="100" class="data"><input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="a.address3" checked [value]="{{a.address3}}"/>{{a.address3}}</div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<div fxHide.gt-sm class="divider"></div>-->
                            </div>  


                  </div>     
      </div>
   </div>      

   <!---->

    <!--  <div class-"btn-b"><input type="button" id="sendClientInfobtn" value=""><input type="button" id="Closebtn" value="Cancel"> </div> -->

   <!---->
```

client.info.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit }              from '@angular/core';
    import { Input }                          from '@angular/core';

    import { CoreService }                    from 'app/core/service/core.service';
    import { FaService }                      from '../../service/fa.service';
    import { ClientAccountModel } from "app/fa/model/client-account.model";
    import { ClientModel } from "app/fa/model/client.model";

    @Component({
      selector: 'fa-edit-client-info',
      templateUrl: './fa-edit-client-info.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./fa-edit-client-info.component.css', '../fa.css']
    })
    export class FaEditClientInfoListComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() clientId: string = "";
      // public clientAccountsArray: ClientAccountModel[];
      // public totalAccounts: number = 0;


      public popUpTitle = "Loan Particiapnts";
      public clientsArray: ClientModel[] = [];
      public openedIndex: number = -1;
      public totalClients: number = 0;



      constructor( 
        private coreService: CoreService,
        private faService: FaService
      ) { 
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log("cliendid " +this.clientId);
        this.initData();

/*************/
        this.client = {
    workPhone: this.client.workPhone,
    homePhone: this.client.homePhone
  };
/***************/
      }

      initData(): void {
        let isEligible:boolean = true;
        this.faService.getLoanParticpantDetailsAlt(this.clientId)
          .subscribe(
            successModel => {
            this.clientsArray = successModel;
              this.totalClients = this.clientsArray.length;
            },
            error => {
              this.onError(error);
            }
          );
      }



      doSelect(): void {
        this.coreService.closeModal("");
      }

      onError(error): void {
        console.log("ERROR!: " + error);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing like this in my projects

```
<input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="radioData" [value]="a.workPhone"/>
<input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="radioData" [value]="a.workPhone"/>
<input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="radioData" [value]="a.workPhone"/>
<input type="radio"  name="address" [(ngModel)]="radioData" [value]="a.workPhone"/>
```

by doing this  `ngModel` will be change when u click the radio button according to its input value

`client.info.ts` I suggest you to follow angular rules to naming component like this `client-info.component.ts`

In your component class u simply delcare `radioData`

```
export class ClientInfoComponent implements OnInit {
    public radioData: any; <--- your radio data will be updated when on click

    ngOnInit() {
      // initialize your radio with value
       this.radioData = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i handles the selected radio values in client.info.ts

Comment: as of angular 2/4 final release use `[value]` instead of `value`

Comment: u initialized the radioData but how do u show selected radioData value in client-info.component.ts - thanks

Comment: ngmodel is a two way binder. when u select any radio button it's value will be assigned to the `radioData`. then create ur logic and simply call the `radioData` you will get your selected radio button value

Comment: In Html if a radioData value changes in component it will automatically change the view according to the value

Comment: @SheikAlthaf i am kinda new to typescript and angular .Can you show me an example when u say logic and make a call? do u mean If I just call this .radioData. it will display the home or workPhone based on user selection? - thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms go to this link and study about reactive forms. It's very easy to learn.

Comment: If this post is helpful dont forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

either use template driven form and [(ng-model)] and to get "value" of the check Box or use Reactive form and use form-control name property to get value of the input assigned to the model.

Comment: as of angular > 2.1 use `[(ngModel)]`

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the `FormsModule` or Reactive Forms  for dealing with form inputs

`FormsModule` Approach

add this to your **app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ], // import forms module
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

then inside your **component.html**

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="client.homePhone" [value]="client.homePhone"> 
  {{client.homePhone}}
</div>

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="phone" [(ngModel)]="client.workPhone" [value]="client.workPhone"> 
  {{client.workPhone}}
</div>
```

inside your **component.ts** create a model for the `client` object

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.client = {
    workPhone: '',
    homePhone: ''
  };
}
```

you can use the values from the object anywhere inside the component by referencing the required properties. For eg, if you want to access workPhone use `this.client.workPhone`.

Comment: I noticed you are using client.homePhone  can you explain? I am goign through a for loop to populate the radio phone numbers from JSON using a loop   <div  *ngFor="let a of clientsArray; let i = index;" > <input type="radio"  name="phone"  [(ngModel)]="a.homePhone" checked [value]="{{a.homePhone}}"/> {{a.homePhone}} (Home). </div>   . I am using a.homePhone to get the values, how would I incorporate urs with mine?