# Angular - list of radio button not working

Tags: forms, angular, radio-button

I'm having problems using a list of radio buttons inside a form. Below my code.
**view**

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="perito">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <table class="table">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let p of periti">
                    <td>{{p.nome}} {{p.cognome}}</td>
                    <td>{{p.indirizzo}} {{p.civico}} - {{p.cap}} 
                        {{p.comune}}
                    </td>
                    <td><input formControlName="idPerito" type="radio" [value]="p.id" (change)="onSelect(p.id)"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
perito: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
    this.perito = new FormGroup({
        idPerito: new FormControl()
    });
}
onSelect() {
    console.log(this.perito.value);
}
```

The problem is that when I select one radio button:

1. all the other radio button get selected too
2. the form object is undefined

What is the correct way to manage a list of radio button? Thanks.

EDIT - this is how I populate my `periti` array:

```
this.peritiSrv.getPeriti()
    .then(res => {
        this.periti = res;
     })
     .catch();
```

Anyway, it cannot happen to have the same id for two `periti` objects, because they are primary keys.

Comment: Can you provide your periti array? Maybe somewhere you have same ids.Because this could happen if your values for radio buttons are the same.

Comment: see my edit, thanks.

Comment: I meant to give an example of that array.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177562/angular-2-4-how-to-pass-capture-radio-button-values-using-angular-typescript/46178438#46178438

Answer (score 0):

Your form object is `undefined` probably because it was not instantiated by the time your component was created (`construct`ed). Try to move the `formGroup` creation line to the body of the `constructor` for that component from the `ngOnInit()` hook,

> controller

```
perito: FormGroup;
constructor() {
    this.perito = new FormGroup({
        idPerito: new FormControl('')
    }); // empty string passed in as the initial value of the FormControl instead of no argument
}
// no ngOnInit() implementation
onSelect() {
    console.log(this.perito.value);
}
```

See if the problem persists.

Comment: The problem is still there. I think (but I can be wrong) that the object is undefined because since both radio button are selected the controller doesn't know which is the passed value.